# how to work with google license verification library in apportable

Tags: apportable

I am converting my iOS app to android using apportable, I need help implementing google play licensing into my code, I am confused about how to include google play license verification library (LVL)into my code. I know how to call java code using Bridgekit but how will I include LVL, because when we work in eclipse we need to download and install Google Market Licensing package from sdk manager.

what steps do i have to take to include LVL into my project and start coding

Answer (score 1):

The Apportable platform already includes the required LVL libraries, since they are required for the Google Expansion Files feature.

You should be able to follow all the other steps in the docs: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

For more info on how to add the check_license permission, see the android manifest documentation: http://docs.apportable.com/config.html#manifest-options

For adding the Google "public key string" (via the SIGNING_PUBKEY environment variable) see the expansion files documentation: http://docs.apportable.com/publishing.html#large-installers

The rest should be possible via BridgeKit and maybe also by adding a small java shim.